# iText and Shadow attacks

Tags: security, itext, digital-signature, itext7

I want to know if iText is researching or have already patched shadow attacks described here: https://www.pdf-insecurity.org/
Shadow Attacks: Hiding and Replacing Content in Signed PDFs (July 2020)
I've just found information about vulnerabiities discovered in 2019
https://itextpdf.com/en/blog/technical-notes/avoiding-pdf-digital-signature-vulnerabilities-itext

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and sorry, I am in Argentina :) Ok I will check iText blog tomorrow, I am developing with iText 5 and I would like to know if you are gonna patch this version (as you have made it in version 5.5.13.1 for attacks discovered in 2019). Best regards

Comment: 5.5.13.1 does not require a patch for this attack, as you can see from @mkl post below. Having said that, we are planning on releasing 5.5.13.2 during this month (August 2020), as a maintenance release.

Comment: https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it5kb/releases/release-itext-5-5-13-2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, iText does not need to be patched, neither in versions 7.x nor in versions 5.5.x.

In either case the method that checks whether any changes were made to a signed PDF by means of incremental updates, `SignatureUtil.signatureCoversWholeDocument` and `AcroFields.signatureCoversWholeDocument` respectively, reports `false` in case of the manipulated examples provided on the pdf-insecurity site, i.e. it reports that some kind of changes were added after signing.

Furthermore, in either case the method that retrieves the signed revision, `SignatureUtil.extractRevision` and `AcroFields.extractRevision` respectively, also returns the original, not yet manipulated, signed revision for those examples.

This behavior is not surprising. The description of the shadow attacks clearly indicates that these attacks are applied to the PDF by means of an *incremental update* (called an *Incremental Saving* in the vulnerability report by the RUB researchers). The `signatureCoversWholeDocument` method now checks exactly whether the file has no content after the signed revision; thus, it detects the incremental update added by shadow attacks. And the `extractRevision` method returns the file up to the end of the corresponding signed ranges; thus, it does not return any addition from the incremental update applied by the shadow attack.

Just to be sure I checked the iText 7 `signatureCoversWholeDocument` output for the manipulated example documents, see [this ShadowAttacks unit test](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/signature/ShadowAttacks.java), and as expected the method reported that the signature in question did not cover the whole document.

---

The vulnerability report can be read to call a behavior like that of iText a "limited vulnerability" described as

> the same warning is raised in case
> of an *allowed* modification (e.g., commenting) as well as in case of *unallowed*
> modifications (attacks). Victims are unable to distinguish between both cases.

*([Vulnerability Report - Attacks bypassing the signature validation in PDF - 2020-03-02](https://www.pdf-insecurity.org/download/report-pdf-signatures-2020-03-02.pdf))*

In my opinion this terminology only makes sense if the software in question promised otherwise, i.e. to differentiate between allowed and disallowed changes and to report accordingly. Otherwise it's not a *vulnerability* but a (hopefully documented) *behavior*, and *vulnerable* only is a user who incorrectly expects a different behavior.

As far as I know iText has not promised to analyse the changes in incremental updates (in excess to retrieving LTV information). Bruno Lowagie in his iText whitepaper on digital signatures for PDFs wrote that an analysis had been put onto the development roadmap; to my knowledge, though, there is no (public) implementation thereof available currently.

Thus, I wouldn't call the behavior of iText in particular a "limited vulnerability".

Of course, if some software is *based* on iText for signature validation and *does promise* to recognize allowed and disallowed changes based on the validation results of iText explained above, that software indeed has at least a limited vulnerability to shadow attacks unless reporting them as *disallowed changes*.

---

It is very likely that at least the widely used validators reported as vulnerable, foremost Adobe Acrobat Reader, will quickly try to correct their code to at least indicate the presence of changes or even to report them as disallowed. Nonetheless, it may make sense to try and implement some methods that check for signs of preparations for shadow attacks. I'm currently playing around with some proofs-of-concepts in this regard.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, you have clarified me a lot! I will check for changes after the last signature, and warn the user in case of finding them. I think that analyse if those changes were allowed or not represents to me a lot of effort  and a heavy responsibility. Furthermore, I don't suppose to have a lot of that kind of situations. Thanks for the example. Best regards.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: By the way, Adobe Reader appears to be hardened against Shadow Attacks since version 2020.009.20063, see the Adobe Security Bulletin [APSB20-24](https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/acrobat/apsb20-24.html).